# Connection to Realm server fails

Tags: ios, macos, terminal, realm

I have followed steps for install realm server as per below link : 
https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/latest/#automatic-install
Attaching screenshot of terminal

[image]

But when I open RealmStudio and connect to server, it gives error could not reach the server.

[image]

Comment: You need to run `ros start`

Comment: -bash: ros: command not found @EpicPandaForce

Comment: @EpicPandaForce can you tell me what should I do?

Comment: Find the ROS command line thing and start the server :D